# How to get last 5 days messages from Kafka using Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have set TTL for a topic in Kafka as 7 days, I am getting data from `Kafka` and storing it in DB, but from last 5 days My DB server was down, now I have to fetch last 5 days messages from `Kafka` and store them in DB
Note: From last 5 days there is no problem with `Kafka`.

Comment: You need to consume with the help of offset values. For an example, If your last read is offset 100, then you need to consume it from the offset 101.

Comment: How can use this offset concept in Java and how do I know the last offset value of stored message, because I am not storing any offset value

Answer (score 8):

First call consumer.partitionsFor() method to get the partitions for your topic

https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#partitionsFor(java.lang.String)

Then call consumer.offsetsForTimes() to get the offsets for each partition for the timestamp 5 days ago when the last message was successfully processed.

https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes(java.util.Map)

Then call consumer.seek() to position the current consumer offset at that point in time and continue to call poll() and process messages as you would normally.

https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,%20long)

Answer (score 2):

To the previous Nice Answer, I would add that call `partitionsFor` method to get  the partitions for your topic, and then do as @Hans said.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer to include the proper first step.